# Module scope not right

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to be dry by moving common methods into a module or a class and have it included/inherited in new classes that are namespaced under different modules. If I have two classes namespaces under the same module, then I can call them without including module name as long as I am under the same namespace. But if i have a method included from different module than my namespace scope changes and I dont know why or how to avoid it.

For example. this code works and returns 'bar':

```
module Foo
  class Bar
    def test_it
      Helper.new.foo
    end
  end
end

module Foo
  class Helper
    def foo
      'bar'
    end
  end
end

Foo::Bar.new.test_it
```

but if I move out method test_it into a module, then it doesnt work anymore: NameError: uninitialized constant Mixins::A::Helper.

```
module Mixins; end

module Mixins::A
  def self.included(base)
    base.class_eval do
      def test_it
        Helper.new.foo
      end
    end
  end
end

module Foo
  class Bar
    include Mixins::A
  end
end

module Foo
  class Helper
    def foo
      'bar'
    end
  end
end

Foo::Bar.new.test_it
```

Moreover if class_eval is evaling string instead of block, scope becomes Foo::Bar instead of Foo.

```
module Mixins; end

module Mixins::A
  def self.included(base)
    base.class_eval %q{
      def test_it
        Helper.new.foo
      end
    }
  end
end

module Foo
  class Bar
    include Mixins::A
  end
end

module Foo
  class Helper
    def foo
      'bar'
    end
  end
end

Foo::Bar.new.test_it
```

anyone got ideas?

EDIT:

Thanks to Wizard and Alex, I ended up with this code which is not beautiful but does the job (*note it is using Rails helper constantize*):

```
module Mixins; end

module Mixins::A
  def self.included(base)
    base.class_eval do
      def test_it
        _nesting::Helper
      end
      def _nesting
        @_nesting ||= self.class.name.split('::')[0..-2].join('::').constantize
      end
    end
  end
end

module Foo 
  class Helper
  end

  class Bar
    include Mixins::A
  end
end

module Foo2 
  class Helper
  end

  class Bar
    include Mixins::A
  end
end

Foo::Bar.new.test_it    #=> returns Foo::Helper
Foo2::Bar.new.test_it   #=> returns Foo2::Helper
```

Comment: Glad you got a solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand this problem, you need to understand how constant lookup works in Ruby. It's not the same as method lookup. In this code:

```
module Mixins::A
  def self.included(base)
    base.class_eval do
      def test_it
        Helper.new.foo
      end
    end
  end
end
```

`Helper` refers to a constant called "Helper" which is either in `A`, `Mixins`, or defined at the top level (ie. in `Object`), *not* a constant called "Helper" which is defined in `Bar`. Just because you `class_eval` this code with class `Bar`, doesn't change that. If you know the difference between "lexical binding" and "dynamic binding", then you can say that constant resolution in Ruby uses *lexical* binding. You are expecting it to use dynamic binding.

Remember that the block which you are passing to `base.class_eval` is compiled to bytecode *once*, and subsequently, every time the `included` hook is called, that same precompiled block (including the reference to `Helper`) is executed with a different class (`base`) as `self`. The interpreter does not parse and compile the block afresh every time you execute `base.class_eval`.

On the other hand, if you pass a *String* to `class_eval`, that string is parsed and compiled afresh *every time* the `included` hook runs. IMPORTANT: code which is `eval`ed from a String is evaluated in a *null lexical environment*. That means that local variables from the surrounding method are *not* available to the code being `eval`ed from the string. More to the point for you, it also means that the surrounding scope will not affect constant lookup from within the `eval`ed code.

If you do want a constant reference to be resolved dynamically, an explicit constant reference will never work. That's simply not the way the language is intended to work (and for good reason). Think about it: if constant references were resolved dynamically, depending on the class of `self`, you could never predict how references to things like `Array` or `Hash` would be resolved at runtime. If you has code like this in a module...

```
hash = Hash[array.map { |x| ... }]
```

...And the module was mixed in to a class with a nested `Hash` class, `Hash.[]` would refer to the *nested class* rather than `Hash` from the standard library! Clearly, resolving constant references dynamically has just too much potential for name clashes and related bugs.

Now with method lookup, that's a different thing. The whole concept of OOP (at least the Ruby flavor of OOP) is that what a method call (ie. a message) does depends on the class of the receiver.

If you do want to find a constant dynamically, depending on the class of the receiver, you can do it using `self.class.const_get`. This is arguably cleaner than `eval`ing a String to achieve the same effect.

Comment: Thanks. That explains a lot. I am still confused why is nesting changing if I am doing class_eval with string instead of block. I get [Mixins::A, Foo::Bar] with string class_eval and [Mixins::A] with block class_eval.

Comment: Thanks for the great info. The scoping makes sense, just had to think about it and look for a way around.

Comment: @luriG, it took me quite a while to get back to this. Hopefully the added information will help you understand why `eval`ing a block and a string can yield different results.

Answer (score 0):

```
module Mixins::A
  def self.included(base)
    base.class_eval do
      def test_it
        Foo::Helper.new.foo
```

---

EDIT:

After getting a chance to play around with code a bit I see more of the problem.  I don't think you'll be able to do exactly what you were attempting, but this is close:

```
module Mixins::A
  def self.included(base)
    base.class_eval do
      def test_it
        self.class.const_get(:Helper).new.foo
      end
    end
  end
end

module Foo
  class Bar
    include Mixins::A
  end
end

module Foo
  class Bar::Helper
    def foo
      'bar'
    end
  end
end
```

Note that the Helper class needed to be namespaced under Foo::Bar due to way constants get resolved in Ruby.

Comment: code is not overcomplicated, I just simplified my case so much that the problem seems overcomplicated. Your answer doesnt solve my problem. If I was too include your mixin in module "Foo2" it would call Foo::Helper instead of Foo2::Helper and that is the reason why I dont want to explicitly specify top level namespace and resolve it dynamically.

Comment: I see.  Try defining `Helper` in your module before including `Mixens::A`.

Comment: One last attempt at this interesting problem.  Please see the edit above.

Comment: THank you for your response. unfortunately I cannot namespace helper under Bar (I am working with rails engine and my models need to be under top level module which is the name of engine). I did similar thing that you proposed - used self.class to get correct namespace. it looks hackish but does the job right now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Constant-lookup in Ruby has changed with respect to #class_eval over the past few major releases. See this post for more information: http://jfire.posterous.com/constant-lookup-in-ruby